# What ecommerce script is /pws/ShippingOptions.ice?

Tags: e-commerce

I recently noticed lots of stores using the same URLS I cant seem to find what it is that is powering their stores:

```
/pws/ShippingOptions.ice?viewBasket=true
```

If you Google that you can see it has lots of different sites that it uses. My first choice was Venda, then tried ATG Commerce, IBM Websphere.. I can't seem to figure it out!

Thanks

Comment: Go it - I think it is : http://www.btexpedite.com/services-solutions/ecommerce/ a first time for me seeing this - anything with BT and it rings alarm bells for developers, JJB sports is on their and they use that URL format in their pages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is FrescaCommerce Platform. Now merged as BT Expedite & Fresca, Multichannel Retail.